# Web Android virtual machine or emulator?

Tags: android, mobile, web, virtual-machine, emulation

I develop Android app's with a group of several professionals, often they come to my desk so I would install the latest compile version on their devices. 
I was wondering if there is any tool like a web Dalvik (Android Virtual Machine) to show my app, maybe some Android web emulator.

Regards Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Manymo](https://www.manymo.com/). It's very full featured and pretty lightweight.